# Trigger mouse click on a button each 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, dom, triggers, click, muse

How to trigger a mouse click on the element (slider "next" button) each X seconds?

I have built a website in Adobe Muse, but the slider widget doesn’t have an auto play function, and I’m trying to make the next button click each 5 seconds to simulate autoplay. I’ve found the class for the button

```
<div class="fp-controlArrow fp-next"></div>
```

maybe there is even a chance to trigger clicking it somehow? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to specify both classes to trigger the button and use a bit more difficult command. This worked:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {

document.querySelector('.fp-controlArrow.fp-next').click();


}, 5000);
```

**Now I have additional question: is it possible to stop clicking after user will click either back or next button with a mouse?**

As a half-measure I’ve set it to stop at about a time it returns to the first slide but it would be much better to stop it after user clicks any of the button...

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {

document.querySelector('.fp-controlArrow.fp-next').click();


}, 7000);

setTimeout(function( ) { clearInterval( interval ); }, 44000);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval):

```
setInterval(() => {
  element.click()
}, 5000)
```

where `element` is a reference to your DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

you can store your interval on a variable and stop it whenever you want

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    button.click();
    // [button] here is the element you found with the specified class
    // if you're using jQuery
    // you can get you button and trigger the event
    // beware of other buttons using the same class
    jQuery(".fp-next").trigger("click");
}, 5000);

//if you want to stop it 

clearInterval(interval);
```